# Correct index for partial search in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, filter, wildcard

I have 3 fields, ID, reference_id, and postal_code. I would like to be able to search using these fields, e.g.:

If ID is ABCDEFGH, searching DEF will show it.
If there are postal codes 29019 and 27829, searching 2 will show both. Search 29 will show 29019

Is this autocomplete filter? or wildcard filter? I read in Elastic docs that its bad to put * in front and end of the value of wildcard filter, so I'm wondering what's the best filter to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your required use case by using both ngram and edge n-gram tokenizer.

Adding a working example with index mapping, index data, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
        },
        "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "edge_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        },
        "edge_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "index.max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ID": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
      },
      "postal_codes": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer":"edge_ngram_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "postal_codes": "27829"
}
{
  "ID": "ABCDEFGH"
}
{
  "postal_codes": "29019"
}
```

> If ID is ABCDEFGH, searching DEF will show it.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "ID": "DEF"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66778583",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "ID": "ABCDEFGH"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

> searching 2 will show both

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "postal_codes": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66778583",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "postal_codes": "27829"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66778583",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "postal_codes": "29019"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

> Search 29 will show 29019

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "postal_codes": "29"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66778583",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "postal_codes": "29019"
        }
      }
    ]
```